# MSAL Login with NGRX state management

Tags: angular, azure, ngrx, state-management, msal

I'm using MSAL login which automatically redirect to microsoft login page but when I set cache location to 'none' instead of 'localStorage' it's not redirecting

I don't want to store token in local Storage, How Can I fix this and use NGRX to store token
Please help

````
  || window.navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Trident/') > -1;
  
export const protectedResourceMap: any = [
  [environment.baseURL, environment.scopedUri],
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    MsalModule.forRoot(new PublicClientApplication
      (
        {
          auth:{
            clientId:environment.uiClientId,
            redirectUri:environment.redirectUri,
            authority:'https://login.microsoftonline.com/'+ environment.tenantId
          },
          cache:
          {
            cacheLocation:'localStorage',
            storeAuthStateInCookie:isIE
          }
        }
      ),
      {
        interactionType:InteractionType.Redirect,
        authRequest:{
          scopes:['user.read']
        }
      },
      {
        interactionType:InteractionType.Redirect,
        protectedResourceMap:new Map(
          [
            ['https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me',['user.Read']],
            ['localhost',[environment.apiScope]]
          ]
        )
      }
    )
  ],
  providers: [
      { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: MsalInterceptor, multi: true },
  ],
  bootstrap: [
    AppComponent
    , MsalRedirectComponent
  ]
})
export class AppModule { }```

Need to implement NGRX
````

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://azuread.github.io/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/docs/msal/modules/_configuration_.html#cachelocation) you can only store tokens in `localStorage` or `sessionStorage`.

Btw you don't need to handle this token in `MSAL`. You need to listen to local storage in NGRX effects for this specific token and then put it into the NGRX store using an action.

NGRX effect will be similar to the following:

```js
 listenToMsalKey$ = createEffect(() =>
    fromEvent<StorageEvent>(window, 'storage').pipe(
      ofType<StorageEvent>('storage'),
      map((event: StorageEvent) => {
        if (event.key === 'msalToken') {
          // Dispatch an action with the new value
          return { type: '[Msal Storage] Token Changed', payload: event.newValue };
        }
      })
    )
  );
```

and then you can access your token using a selector in other parts of your app.